# Media Controllers are not visible on the top of the surface view

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Media Controllers are not visible on the top of the surface view .I have tried almost all the options

1. Surface View should disappear  every time an channel is clicked from the list.
2. Then the Flip animation for the background Images  takes place.
3. Then the Surface should be visible.
4. The above three steps happen  for every click.

Every time  i have tried doing the below give things. Surface View would disappear the first time But appear while the flip animation is happening  and the n Never disppears

1. Set Visibility(inivisible ,gone )- nothing works
2. Changing the size of the surface view
3. BringToFront paired with invalidate()

Finally i tried

```
mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(true);  
mHolder.setPixelFormat(Transparent)
```

That Worked But now the Problem is My Media Controllers that were attached to FrameLayout  are not getting displayedand the Reason is ofcourse

```
mSurface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Can Any body please please please to power of infinity  tell me what should i do to get the media controllers  to show up or get the whole Scenario worked out .

I am quite new to media player and surface views.

Please Help

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.user_main_screen);

        ActionBar  actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
        //         // get action bar   
        //        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        // 
        //        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        //        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        SetUpVariables();

        getDataFromSignIn();


        Categories categoriesList = new Categories(UserMainScreen.this); 
        try {
            resultFromCategoriesAsyncTask=  categoriesList.execute(AccessToken).get();


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Language LanguagesList = new Language(UserMainScreen.this); 
        try {
            resultFromLanguagesAsyncTask=  LanguagesList.execute(AccessToken).get();


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen(UserMainScreen.this); 
        try {
            resultFromAsyncTask=  mainScreen.execute(AccessToken).get();


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            getChannelInfo(resultFromAsyncTask);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*
         * changed the Thread variable policy variable -lalita  */
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy1 = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy1); 
        ParentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        PreviewFrameImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.previewScreenImageView);
        PreviewFrameImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Bitmap PreviewImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tvscreen_white);
        PreviewFrameImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( PreviewImage, 350 , 180 , true));

        PreviewFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer); 
        mSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_main); 
        mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(true);  
        //  mSurface.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //PreviewFrame.removeView(mSurface);


        mHolder = mSurface.getHolder();
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);        
        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        controller = new VideoControllerView(this); 

        //      youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        //      youTubeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);       
        InitImgList();

        Integer[] images = (Integer[])imgList.toArray(new Integer[imgList.size()]); 

        for( int i = 0; i <ChannelThumbnails.size() ; i++)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"ResponseData----- lalita test ---- channel  Image Path "+ChannelThumbnails.get(i));
        }
        com.ib.coverflow.FlowImageAdapter coverImageAdapter = new  com.ib.coverflow.FlowImageAdapter(this,ChannelThumbnails.toArray( new String[ChannelThumbnails.size()]),180, 150);
        //coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();
        CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);
        //coverFlow.setSpacing(-20);
        coverFlow.setSelection(30);
        setupListeners(coverFlow);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.user_main_screen_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * On selecting action bar icons
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {      
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            // refresh
            return true;
        case R.id.action_user:
            // help action
            return true;
        case R.id.action_menu:
            // check for updates action
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void InitImgList() {
        imgList.add(R.drawable.img01);
        imgList.add(R.drawable.img02);
        imgList.add(R.drawable.img03);
        imgList.add(R.drawable.img04);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void getChannelInfo(String ResultDataFroMsERVER) throws JSONException    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        channelInfo = resultFromAsyncTask;
        Log.e(TAG,"channel Information   " +channelInfo );  

        /*
         * Json object for parsing the data(Channel Info)
//           */
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(channelInfo);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       


        try {
            ResponseData= json.getJSONArray("Response Data");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i=0 ; i <ResponseData.length();i++)
        {
            jsonobjectresponsedata = ResponseData.getJSONObject(i);         
            ChannelID.add(jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("channel_id")) ;
            ChannelType.add(jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("channel_type")) ;
            VideoType.add(jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("video_type")) ;
            ChannelName.add(jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("name")) ;
            channelLink.add(jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("link")) ;
            ChannelThumbnails.add( jsonobjectresponsedata.getString("img_path")) ;           
        }
    }

    private void getDataFromSignIn() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent  InfoFromSignScreen = getIntent();
        UserName =  InfoFromSignScreen.getCharSequenceExtra("UserName").toString();
        AccessToken = InfoFromSignScreen.getCharSequenceExtra("AccessToken").toString();    
        Log.e (TAG, "LALITA TEST ***************** USERNAME AND aCCESS TOKEN "  +   UserName + "  "+AccessToken);
    }


    private void SetUpVariables() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);    
    }


    private void FlipImageViewOnClick() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(PreviewFrameImage, "rotationY", 0.0f, 180f);

        animation.setDuration(1500); 
        animation.setRepeatCount(0);
        //animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        animation.start();
        animation.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //PreviewFrameImage.bringToFront();
                // mSurface.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ANimation START ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ANimationREPEAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PreviewFrameImage.setRotationY(0);  
                //  mSurface.bringToFront();
                //  mSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ANimation Endded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Setup cover flow.
     * 
     * @param mCoverFlow
     *            the m cover flow
     * @param reflect
     *            the reflect
     */

    /**
     * Sets the up listeners.
     * 
     * @param mCoverFlow
     *            the new up listeners
     */
    private void setupListeners(final CoverFlow coverFlow) {



        coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /*
                 * Hls Streams
                 */

                if(channelLink.get(position).endsWith("m3u8")) {

                    Log.e(TAG," ******* HLS*************** "  +channelLink.get(position) ); 
                    if(mMediaPlayer!= null )
                    {   
                        // mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(true);  
                        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
                        controller.hide();  

                        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        {
                            mMediaPlayer.stop();                        
                        }

                        mMediaPlayer.reset();                        
                        mMediaPlayer.release(); 

                        FlipImageViewOnClick();
                        // mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(false);  

                        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
                        // mSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //PreviewFrame.addView(mSurface);

                        // mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(false);  

                        playHlsStreams(channelLink.get(position));                       
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        FlipImageViewOnClick(); 

                        //mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(false);  

                        //  mSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //  PreviewFrame.addView(mSurface);
                        //   mSurface .setZOrderOnTop(false);  

                        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

                        //mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
                        playHlsStreams(channelLink.get(position));
                    }
                }
                /*
                 * Octoshape Streams
                 */
                else if (channelLink.get(position).startsWith("octoshape"))
                {

                    Log.e(TAG," octoshape "  +channelLink.get(position) );  

                    if(mMediaPlayer != null)
                    {

                        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);                      
                        controller.hide();                       
                        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        {
                            mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        }                               
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();                            
                        mMediaPlayer.release();                     

                        FlipImageViewOnClick();

                        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
                        initOctoshapeSystem(channelLink.get(position)) ;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        FlipImageViewOnClick(); 
                        initOctoshapeSystem(channelLink.get(position)) ;
                                        }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Youtube Work In Progress and RTMP PLAYER NOT AVAILABLE  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });  
    }
    private void playHlsStreams(String OCTOLINK1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  



        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(PreviewFrame); 
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder);            
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(OCTOLINK1));
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaPlayer.start();    


    }   

    public void initOctoshapeSystem(final String OCTOLINK1) 
    {
        os = OctoshapeSystemCreator.create(this, problemListener,
                new OctoshapePortListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPortBound(int port) {
                setupStream(OCTOLINK1).requestPlay();
            }
        }, Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage());
        os.setProblemMessageLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage());
        os.setProblemListener(problemListener);

        os.addPlayerNameAndVersion(MediaPlayerConstants.NATIVE_PLAYER, MediaPlayerConstants.NATIVE_PLAYER,
                "" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        os.open();
    }

    public StreamPlayer setupStream(final String stream) {

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Setting up stream: " + stream);
        StreamPlayer sp = os.createStreamPlayer(stream);

        sp.setProblemListener(new ProblemListener() {

            @Override
            public void gotProblem(Problem p) {
                StreamStatus="No Stream/Internet Problem";
                Log.i("Stream Status  ", "Not Ok");
                active="yellow";

                Log.e(LOGTAG, stream+": "+p.getMessage() + " " + p.toString());               
            }
        });
        sp.setListener(new StreamPlayerListener() {
            private String playerId;


            @Override
            public void gotUrl(String url, long seekOffset,
                    boolean playAfterBuffer) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "gotUrl");
                if (playAfterBuffer)
                    urlQueue.add(Uri.parse(url));
                else
                    playStream(Uri.parse(url), playerId);
            }

            @Override
            public void gotNewOnDemandStreamDuration(long duration) {
            }

            @Override
            public void resolvedNativeSeek(boolean isLive, String playerId) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "resolvedNativeSeek");
                this.playerId = playerId;
            }

            @Override
            public void resolvedNoSeek(boolean isLive, String playerId) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "resolvedNoSeek");
                this.playerId = playerId;
            }

            @Override
            /**
             * Called when stream support OsaSeek / DVR
             */
            public void resolvedOsaSeek(boolean isLive, long duration,
                    String playerId) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "resolvedOsaSeek");
                this.playerId = playerId;
            }
        });
        //sp.initialize(false);
        return sp;
    }

    protected void playStream(Uri mediaUrl, final String playerId) {

        Log.d(LOGTAG, playerId + " now plays: " + mediaUrl);

        try {

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
            controller.setAnchorView(PreviewFrame);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mHolder); 
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, mediaUrl);

            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if (!urlQueue.isEmpty())
                        playStream(urlQueue.removeFirst(), playerId);
                }

            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    error("MediaPlayer Error: " + what + ":" + extra);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error preparing MediaPlayer", e);
            error("Error preparing MediaPlayer: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams vLayout = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mSurface
                .getLayoutParams();
        mSurface.setLayoutParams(vLayout);
        // dialog.dismiss();
        StreamStatus="Stream Ok";
        Log.i("Stream Stattus", "Stream Ok");

        active="true";
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"+startTime);


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 50000, 60000);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        if (os != null) {
            os.close(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    UserMainScreen.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "MY onStop is called");
        shutdown();
    }
    ProblemListener problemListener = new ProblemListener() {
        @Override
        public void gotProblem(Problem p) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, p.getMessage() + "\n" + p.toString());
            error(p.getMessage());
        }
    };

    protected void error(final String error) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    //  dialog.show();
                    Log.i(LOGTAG, "problem dialog block");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    class SayHello extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Catche clear method scheduled");
            clearCache();
        }
    }
    void clearCache() 
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "clearCache() clled");
        if (mClearCacheObserver == null) 
        {
            mClearCacheObserver=new CachePackageDataObserver();
        }

        PackageManager mPM=getPackageManager();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final Class[] classes= { Long.TYPE, IPackageDataObserver.class };

        Long localLong=Long.valueOf(CACHE_APP);

        try 
        {
            Method localMethod=
                    mPM.getClass().getMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", classes);


            try 
            {
                localMethod.invoke(mPM, localLong, mClearCacheObserver);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e1)
        {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class CachePackageDataObserver extends IPackageDataObserver.Stub 
    {
        public void onRemoveCompleted(String packageName, boolean succeeded) 
        {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder mHolder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e(TAG,"**************Surface created**************LOLZ ")  ;

        mMediaPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e(TAG,"Surface  CHANGED **************LOLZ ")  ;

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e(TAG,"Surface destroyed **************LOLZ "  );        

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }
    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        //Log.e(TAG, "GET CURRENT POSITION " +mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }
    @Override
    public void start() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isFullScreen() {
        return false;
    }

    public void toggleFullScreen() {

        controller.hide();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();

        //      intent = new Intent(UserMainScreen.this,
        //              MiniAndroidPlayer.class);

        intent.putExtra("OCTO", OCTOLINK1); 
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    // End VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(PreviewFrame == v )
        {
            controller.show(); 

            //mSurface.invalidate();

            Log.e(TAG,  " Preview frame controller Show" +controller.isShown()); 
        }           

        if( mSurface == v   )
        {
            controller.show();  // do things

            //  mSurface.invalidate();
            Log.e(TAG,  " mSurface controller Show" +controller.isShown()); 
        }

        if (PreviewFrameImage == v)
        {
            controller.show();  // do things



            Log.e(TAG,  " PreviewFrameImage controller Show" +controller.isShown()); 
        }

        if ( youTubeView == v) {


            controller.show();  // do things

            //mSurface.invalidate();
            Log.e(TAG,  " youtubeView controller Show" +controller.isShown()); 
            //      
            //          controller.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            //              player.loadVideo(Config.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
            // 
            // Hiding player controls
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            //   done now   getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Uncomment again
     */

    //  private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider()
    //  {
    //      return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    //  }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PreviewFrameImage.setRotationY(-90);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
        .build();


        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCache(new LimitedAgeDiscCache(cacheDir, 60))
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
        .build();
        // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/previewScreenImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" /> 

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_marginBottom="205dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="269dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
        android:text="framelayout"
       >  


   <!--      <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> -->

     <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface_main"
            android:layout_width="484dp"
            android:layout_height="235dp" 
            />       

    </FrameLayout>   

    <com.ib.coverflow.CoverFlow
        xmlns:coverflow ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ib.qezyplay"
        android:id ="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height ="wrap_content"       
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:paddingBottom="20dp">"
    </com.ib.coverflow.CoverFlow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Paste your xml please

Comment: please Answer the above question guuys  please